# Hans Christian Andersen's The Little Mermaid (1975), Old bird movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was really little I had a DVD with Hans Christian Andersen's The Little Mermaid (1975) version on it. There were also two other movies. One of them was about why some birds are grey and some are very colorful. In the movie, the birds live under a rainbow which is attacked by bugs. The ones who fought to save the rainbow were rewarded with colorful feathers while the others stayed grey. The third movie I don't remember very well at all. Something about a little old man who lived in a house in the forest. I think he kills a snake that turns out to be a witch? I may not remember that correctly. If anyone know what either of those two movies are called it would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Were the movies animated? In what language did you view them? Could they have been  e.g.Russian or Czech originally? (Both countries did a lot of animation in the seventies.)

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen All three were animated. Im pretty sure they were anime-style movies as well.

Comment: The one about the birds appears to be of a Japanese story that translates in English to "Rainbow Birds".  I found this link http://hukumusume.com/douwa/English/world/11/04_E.html  hope that helps a bit.